# How to log HTTP requests coming into IIS

Tags: http, iis

I run IIS 5 on my dev machine.  I have an asp.net 3.5 web service running on it which I'm calling from a different web app running on the same server.  My service is returning an error 500 Internal Server error and I'm troubleshooting it.  My request is being sent via a `System.Net.HttpWebReques`t object and it looks valid from the client's perspective.

I'd like to see the raw incoming HTTP request from the server's perspective.  Since the service is being called on loopback, I can't use Wireshark to see it.

IIS Logging shows me the request header but not the post content.

Any suggestions on how I could see the full raw incoming HTTP request in IIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think you want to add an HTTPModule for logging.  [Here's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742398.aspx) a pretty good article on ASP.NET modules and handlers:

That way, when you want to disable logging, you can just remove/comment it from your web.config file.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/)? Just use your machine name instead of localhost.

Comment: Fiddler works if you're querying from a browser.  Webservice calls from within my own apps won't work.

Comment: @Mr Greieves, it takes a little bit of extra work, but you can manually configure the proxy settings for your webservice calls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to log request/response with many data (**request body** included for **http post** etc...), all http verbs included (ex: get, post) using [IIS Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr)

[image]

The request does not necessarily needs to fail to be logged as you can specify there any http status like 200, 401 etc or just all (enter 100-999).

You can also just log requests with a specific URL

[image]

I'll later implement a custom http module for more control.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to run each of your web apps on a different port, and then use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to create a proxy for the port you want to watch. This will monitor all traffic to and from your specific application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code of custom HTTP module we use to log HTTP POST request data.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace MySolution.HttpModules
{
    public class HttpPOSTLogger : IHttpModule
    {

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
        }

        private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != null && sender is HttpApplication)
            {
                var request = (sender as HttpApplication).Request;
                var response = (sender as HttpApplication).Response;

                if (request != null && response != null && request.HttpMethod.ToUpper() == "POST")
                {
                    var body = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(request.Form.ToString());
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(body))
                        response.AppendToLog(body);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Do not forget to register it in web.config of you application.

Use system.WebServer section for IIS Integrated Model

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="HttpPOSTLogger" type="MySolution.HttpModules.HttpPOSTLogger, MySolution.HttpModules" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Use system.web section for IIS Classic Model

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="HttpPOSTLogger" type="MySolution.HttpModules.HttpPOSTLogger, MySolution.HttpModules"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

IIS log Before applying module:

```
::1, -, 10/31/2017, 10:53:20, W3SVC1, machine-name, ::1, 5, 681, 662, 200, 0, POST, /MySolution/MyService.svc/MyMethod, -,
```

IIS log After applying module:

```
::1, -, 10/31/2017, 10:53:20, W3SVC1, machine-name, ::1, 5, 681, 662, 200, 0, POST, /MySolution/MyService.svc/MyMethod, {"model":{"Platform":"Mobile","EntityID":"420003"}},
```

Full article:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1213108/HttpModule-for-logging-HTTP-POST-data-in-IIS-Log